# html2canvas is not exporting SVG to an image on Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

I have an icon SVG and I want to export it to PNG but when I click on the export button in Firefox the image is empty. Chrome works OK.

```js
$('exportbtn').on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
   var element = $(".mobile_frame");
   var imageData;
   html2canvas(element, {
   allowTaint: true,
         logging:true,
      onrendered: function (canvas) {        
      $("#showimage").append(canvas);
      imageData = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
      var newData = imageData.replace(/^data:image\/png/, "data:application/octet-stream");
      $('#exportbtn').attr("download", "layout.png").attr("href", newData);
          }
      });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.4.1/html2canvas.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mobile_frame">
<svg viewBox="-39 -23 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="icon icon_information" style="fill: #673a3a;"><path d="M12.453,1.850 C11.360,2.975 10.814,4.324 10.814,5.897 C10.814,7.471 11.368,8.812 12.477,9.921 C13.585,11.029 14.910,11.583 16.452,11.583 C18.025,11.583 19.375,11.029 20.499,9.921 C21.623,8.812 22.186,7.471 22.186,5.897 C22.186,4.324 21.632,2.975 20.523,1.850 C19.415,0.726 18.058,0.163 16.452,0.163 C14.878,0.163 13.544,0.726 12.453,1.850 ZM16.548,18.040 C16.548,18.040 3.394,20.160 3.394,20.160 C3.394,20.160 2.912,21.702 2.912,21.702 C3.426,21.670 3.892,21.653 4.309,21.653 C5.144,21.653 5.811,21.879 6.309,22.328 C6.807,22.778 7.056,23.292 7.056,23.870 C7.056,24.770 6.798,26.103 6.285,27.869 C6.285,27.869 0.888,46.420 0.888,46.420 C0.438,47.898 0.214,49.118 0.214,50.082 C0.214,51.528 0.711,52.725 1.708,53.672 C2.703,54.619 4.036,55.093 5.707,55.093 C10.107,55.093 14.267,51.689 18.186,44.878 C18.186,44.878 16.837,44.107 16.837,44.107 C15.231,46.613 13.833,48.348 12.645,49.311 C12.227,49.697 11.794,49.889 11.344,49.889 C11.087,49.889 10.846,49.761 10.622,49.504 C10.396,49.247 10.284,48.991 10.284,48.733 C10.284,48.220 10.493,47.175 10.911,45.601 C10.911,45.601 18.861,18.040 18.861,18.040 C18.861,18.040 16.548,18.040 16.548,18.040 Z" fill-rule="evenodd"/></svg></div>
<button id="exportbtn">Save file</button>
<div id="showimage"></div>
```

Comment: @ Robert Longson: "not render good" is not show svg when click button export, image is empty

Comment: Try giving the svg element width and height attributes that are not percentages.

Comment: I have set width height inline but it still does not appear when click button  Export to save file PNG

Comment: @RobertLongson Thank you! Setting px value width and height attributes fixed it for me